# javascript zip folder and sub folder in client machine

Tags: javascript, zip, directory, subdirectory

I want to zip a folder which contain subfolder files in the folder on the client machine.
I am using JavaScript and JSP/HTML , I tried to use [JSzip](http://stuartk.com/jszip/) but I was not successful

```
function zipFolder(){
  var path = "D:/work/poc"; // client machine folder path which has to be zipped 
  var zip = new JSZip();
  zip.folder(path);
  zip.folder(/proj/); // array of size 2
  zip.folder(path).folder(/^vid/); // array of 1
}
```

Comment: JSZip is to zip strings and dataURLs on the client - it cannot access the client machine at all and no current browser can store anything on a named directory on the client for obvious security reasons

Answer (score 0):

You can't, due to security restrictions.  If you could, you would be wide open to some serious security issues.

Answer (score -2):

You **cannot do that** with JavaScript. Available plugins use embedded Flash/SWF for that.

Comment: i want to upload a folder into server what's the best way out ?

Comment: @pradhyumna: `<input type="file" />`.No need for JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks but i want to upload a folder not file :(

Comment: @pradhyumna: I'm afraid that's not possible mate.  For a desktop app that can easily be done, not in the browser client. Ever. You can ask/train your users to upload zip files, maybe?